# visualization of trade flows/trade network between countries in r

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have trade data (exports/imports) of 200 countries of a specific good.
Example:

```
a <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000)
b <- c("countryA", "countryB", "countryC", "countryA", "countryC", "countryA")
c <- c("countryB", "countryC", "countryA", "countryB", "countryA", "countryB")
d<- c(100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 200)
mydata <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
colnames(mydata) <- c("year", "exporteur", "partner", "tradeflow")
```

Now I want to visualize the individual trade flows between the countries in r.

Should look like this:
http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/world.html

Is there any way to do this is r?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks a lot for providing a small, dummy data set and your desired results. Can you also please show us what you have tried yourself. Please read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As you will find in these two links, you should "show your work!". That is: "Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work". Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the `igraph` package. Here is an example of a visual display of a graph using `igraph`.

```
require(igraph)
adj.mat <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), nrow=3)
colnames(adj.mat) <- c("A", "B", "C")
g <- graph.adjacency(adj.mat)
plot(g)
```

On second thought, you can use your data to create a graph with `graph.data.frame`:

```
mydata <- data.frame(b,c,a,d) # different order necessary for graph.data.frame
colnames(mydata) <- c("exporteur", "partner", "year", "tradeflow")
g <- graph.data.frame(mydata)
plot(g)
```